# python flask dictionary database table

Tags: flask

I am  working on an application in Python and Flask where I am creating a query from a database of 50 rows of content that I would like to use to build an HTML table on render.  I will be dealing with 50 rows and 8 fields per row.   What would be the best way to package this up and then render it our in the template.  A sample of a row is below.

```
(49L, 1L, 1L, datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 25, 19, 32, 34), 996L, u'on', 78.0, 80.0, 48.0)
```

i'll be manipulating the datatime for a better display, but most of the other fields will come through basically unchanged.

Thanks!

Comment: To answer my own question for anyone else that needs it.  It's super easy.  All you need to do is to pass the entire query object to the template and access it from there.  For example I changed my query to - queryResult = db.session.query(Reading).order_by(Reading.readingTimestamp.desc()).limit(20)  then I passed queryResult to the template.  Then you can access {{queryResult.whatever}}

Comment: Your comment can and should be the answer (that is considered good form around here).  Just copy and paste it into the answer box and accept it ;-)